# UK visit visa rejection

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds, visa-rejections

My name is Abbas and I am from Pakistan.
I have visited the UK in 2010 on a general visit visa, and again in 2013 on a study visa.
I got married last year with a British girl who stayed with me in Pakistan and went back to the UK in February of this year.
I have a job here in Pakistan in a well-reputed organization.

I applied for a UK visit visa to see my wife who is expecting right now.
I made a very strong case and didn't hide anything in my visa application, but my visa got rejected as they said they are not satisfied with my financial status.

1. I showed living expenses in the UK as 2000 UK pounds which were well above my salary.
2. Two transactions were showing in my salary accounts which were not part of my salary. Even though it was the amount that transferred from my account and then returned to my account on the same day.

Now my question here is that if my wife applies for a spouse visa in the future, will this visit visa rejection affect my case for a spouse visa?
I didn't try to act clever and hide anything but my application still got rejected.
Maybe the immigration agency thought that I have intentions of staying in the UK.

Comment: With UK visa refusals it is very important to see the actual text of the refusal letter. Please upload an image of the refusal letter, with any personal information blacked out.

Comment: You’re asking about a spouse visa. Your question may best be answered under expatriate.